# CSV file not printing?

Tags: python, csv, printing

Can anyone explain why this won't print anything?

```
import csv 

def main():
    with open('MaxWatt1.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `main` function at the end of the program:

```
import csv 

def main():
    with open('MaxWatt1.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row

main() # Call main function.
```

Python does not have a `main` function like C/C++ does (one which gets called implicitly when you run the program).  Instead, Python treats the function you have defined as it would any other function.  The name `main` is only significant to the humans reading your code (and maybe some code analysis tools).

---

Actually, it would probably be best to do:

```
import csv 

def main():
    with open('MaxWatt1.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This ensures that the `main` function is only called when you run the program directly.  If you import your file however, the call to `main` will be skipped.  For more information, see:

[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0):

So to add to what iCodez said:

```
import csv 

def main():
    with open('MaxWatt1.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row

main()
```

will work for you